# Calculating total cost value from multiple select fields

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to calculate the total cost dependant on what is entered into the text field and which package is selected.

```
<label for="_mdjm_event_cost" class="mdjm-label">Total Cost:</label>
<br />&pound;
<input type="text" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="_mdjm_event_cost" class="mdjm-input-currency required" value="" placeholder="0.00" />
<br />
<label for="_mdjm_event_package" class="mdjm-label">Select an Event Package:        </label>
<br />
<select name="_mdjm_event_package" id="_mdjm_event_package">
<option value="" data-price="0.00">No Package</option>
<option value="test" data-price="100.00">Test</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="_mdjm_event_addons" class="mdjm-label">Select Add-ons:</label>
<br />
<select name="_mdjm_event_addons" id="_mdjm_event_addons" multiple="multiple">
<option value="" disabled="disabled" data-price="0.00">EFFECTS</option>
<option value="" disabled="disabled" data-price="0.00">GENERAL</option>
<option value="" disabled="disabled" data-price="0.00">LIGHTING</option>
<option value="mood-lighting" data-price="50.00">Mood Lighting x 3 - &pound;50.00</option>
</select>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
base = 0;
$("#_mdjm_event_cost").on("keyup", function () {
    base = $('#_mdjm_event_cost').val();
});
$("#_mdjm_event_package").on("change", function () {
    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100;
    $("#_mdjm_event_cost").val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

The code is working fine to calculate the new total when a package is selected. I now want to extend it to update the Total Cost field further when an add-on is selected (or de-selected) from the Add-ons multiple select box.

Current working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/tanyk8wu/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I believe I have resolved this with the following updates to the jQuery code...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {https://jsfiddle.net/tanyk8wu/#collaborate
base = 0;
$("#_mdjm_event_cost").on("keyup", function () {
    base = $('#_mdjm_event_cost').val();
});
$('#_mdjm_event_package, #_mdjm_event_addons').change(function () {
    var extras = 0;
    var packages = 0;
    var addons = 0;
    $('#_mdjm_event_package :selected').each(function () {
        packages += Number($(this).data("price"));
    });
    $('#_mdjm_event_addons :selected').each(function () {
        addons += Number($(this).data("price"));
    });
    var extras = ( packages + addons );
    var total = (base * 100 + extras * 100) / 100;
    if (total == "0") {
        $("#_mdjm_event_cost").val('');
    } else {
        $("#_mdjm_event_cost").val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
});
});
```

Seems to work. 
Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/tanyk8wu/5/